# QDataWidgetMapper not working with QLabels

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am using QDataWidgetMapper to map data to a QLineEdit and it works fine. When I use to map data to a QLabel it does not show any data in the label.I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
QDataWidgetMapper *testMapper=new QDataWidgetMapper();

testMapper->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
testMapper->setModel(testModel);


//setting the mapper values to the textboxes ----works fine
testMapper->addMapping(ui->LineEdit1,0);
testMapper->addMapping(ui->LineEdit2,1);

//setting it to qlabels
testMapper->addMapping(ui->label,3);----- does not work
testMapper->toFirst();
```

I am getting the values from the list and attaching the list to the QDataWidgetMapper, from the mapper I am using addMapping to append it to the textboxes. Could anyone let me know why it does not work with qLabels.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, each widget's [user property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#qt-s-property-system) is used to transfer data between the model and the widget. QLabel has no user property. You should use an additional `addMapping()` function enables a named property to be used instead of the default user property.

```
testMapper->addMapping(ui->label,3,"text");
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was almost about to give up with QDataWidgetMapper and implement my own version of it due to the fact that it wasn't working with QLabels...