# Pyqt5 qdatawidgetmapper map data to qlabels

Tags: pyqt5

I have a similar question to this [QDataWidgetMapper not working with QLabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114655/qdatawidgetmapper-not-working-with-qlabels). How do you do this in PYQT5.

Comment: I recommend not only to place the link of the previous answer, you must provide a context to your question.

Comment: Code: `testMapper=QDataWidgetMapper()

testMapper.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
testMapper.setModel(testModel)


testMapper.addMapping(ui.LineEdit1,0)
testMapper.addMapping(ui.LineEdit2,1)

testMapper.addMapping(ui.label,3, "text")
testMapper.toFirst()`

Comment: class NodeEditor(nodeBase, nodeForm):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(nodeBase, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self._dataMapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper()
        
    def setModel(self, proxyModel):
        self._proxyModel = proxyModel
        self._dataMapper.setModel(proxyModel.sourceModel())
        
        self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.uiName, 0)
        self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.uiType, 1) That's a code that works for QLineEdit. I need to map to a Qlable

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46729496/edit) your question and add your code there.!!!!

Comment: It seems that none of your questions have been answered, that should indicate to you that something is doing wrong in your questions. I recommend reading the following to improve: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You must also provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your respose. I tried what you have shown in your code and get the error;  self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.lable, 2,"text")
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addMapping(self, QWidget, int): too many arguments
  addMapping(self, QWidget, int, Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray]): argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]

Comment: If you do not improve your question then I could not help you, take the time to do it as I have taken it to advise you. Change `self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.lable, 2,"text")` to `self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.lable, 2,b"text")`. Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. I will work on my asking. I am using python3. And thank you very much it worked!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by eyllanesc. Thanks a lot.

"if you do not improve your question then I could not help you, take the time to do it as I have taken it to advise you. Change self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.lable, 2,"text") to self._dataMapper.addMapping(self.lable, 2,b"text")"